# Use spread operator (or similar) to pass all properties from a single mixin

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In the example below, I want to pass *only* the properties of `MyMixedInProps` to `MyChildComponent` via something like the spread operator (`{...props}`).

In my real-world example, `MyMixedInProps` is defined in a 3rd-party library (I don't control it) and has many properties that I do not want to define explicitly in the signature of `MyChildComponent`. `MyChildComponent` needs all of the properties of `MyMixedInProps` but should not be passed any of the properties of `MyParentComponentProps`.

**Sample Code:**

```
import React from 'react';

interface MyMixedInProps {
  myMixedInProp1: string;
  myMixedInProp2: string;
  // ... many more props
}

interface MyParentComponentProps {
  myParentProp: string;
}

const MyParentComponent = (props: MyMixedInProps & MyParentComponentProps) =>
  <>
    <MyChildComponent {...props} /> // TODO: exclude props from MyParentComponentProps
    <AnotherChildComponent prop={props.myParentProp} />
  </>;

const MyChildComponent = (props: MyMixedInProps) =>
  <MyComponent myProp1={props.myMixedInProp1} myProp2={props.myMixedInProp2} />
```

**Question:**

Is it possible to use the spread operator (or something similar) in a way that only propagates the properties of one type of a mixin?

**One Failed Attempt:**

I tried using something like the following, but the properties of `MyParentComponentProps` were still passed to `MyChildComponent`.

```
<MyChildComponent {...props as MyMixedInProps} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spread operator you can pick some properties and use the *rest*.
Like that:

```js
const MyParentComponent = (props: MyMixedInProps & MyParentComponentProps) => {
  const {myParentProp, ...mixedProps} = props;
  return <>
    <MyChildComponent {...mixedProps} />
    <AnotherChildComponent prop={myParentProp} />
  </>;
};
```

Comment: Nice! That'll do it. Had no idea how to Google that one. Thanks! https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/commit/80e15d1a10db581bb3df847f7169a6cda9200bee